# Why is the AV_PARSER_PARSE2 in ffmpeg returning empty AVPacket data for HEVC video?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, decode, hevc

I'm attempting to decode an HEVC encoded video (.mp4 format) and extract all the frames in C++. I installed ffmpeg and used one of their examples "video_decode.c", however the AVPacket data (pkt->data) is always NULL/empty and the size of the packet (pkt->size) is always 0.

I have executed ffprobe on the video examples used to ensure that the videos were truly in HEVC format.

I defined the width, height, pixel format, bit rate, and time base of the AVCodec.

I initialized the AVPacket data to NULL and size to 0 manually.

```
const char *filename, *outfilename;
const AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecParserContext *parser;
AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
FILE *f;
AVFrame *frame;
uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
uint8_t *data;
size_t   data_size;
int ret;
AVPacket *pkt;

filename = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Downloads\\video_x265.mp4";
outfilename = "E:\\output\\test%d.pgm";

pkt = av_packet_alloc();
if (!pkt)
    exit(1);
//pkt->data = NULL;
//pkt->size = 0;
/* set end of buffer to 0 (this ensures that no overreading happens for damaged MPEG streams) */
memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);

/* find the MPEG-1 video decoder */
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC);
if (!codec) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
    exit(1);
}

parser = av_parser_init(codec->id);
if (!parser) {
    fprintf(stderr, "parser not found\n");
    exit(1);
}

c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!c) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* For some codecs, such as msmpeg4 and mpeg4, width and height
MUST be initialized there because this information is not
available in the bitstream. */
c->width = WIDTH;
c->height = HEIGHT;
c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
c->bit_rate = 400000;
c->time_base = (AVRational) { 1, 25 };

/* open it */
if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
    exit(1);
}

f = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
    exit(1);
}

frame = av_frame_alloc();
if (!frame) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
    exit(1);
}
frame->width = c->width;
frame->height = c->height;

while (!feof(f)) {
    /* read raw data from the input file */
    data_size = fread(inbuf, 1, INBUF_SIZE, f);
    if (!data_size)
        break;

    /* use the parser to split the data into frames */
    data = inbuf;
    while (data_size > 0) {
        ret = av_parser_parse2(parser, c, &pkt->data, &pkt->size,
                data, data_size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
        printf("pkt size: %d\n",pkt->size);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while parsing\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        data += ret;
        data_size -= ret;

        if (pkt->size)
            decode(c, frame, pkt, outfilename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this flag and set and test if not set: `parser->flags` `PARSER_FLAG_COMPLETE_FRAMES`. And also set/test last parameter to `-1` (pos parameter)

Comment: That seemed to fix things, but now I'm getting the following error:

missing picture in access unit
[hevc @ 0000024a5c9b6880] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0000024a5c9b6880] PPS id out of range: -1
[hevc @ 0000024a5c9b6880] Error parsing NAL unit #0.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Perhaps the `PARSER_FLAG_COMPLETE_FRAMES` flag causes this. It looks like the frame is not complete after all.

Comment: I found these on github: https://github.com/xc724655471/MediaPlayer/blob/13f0f518fd4e9e0ecb763ca1b23bf12bbd1ab249/MediaPlayer/FFmpegDecoder.cpp and https://github.com/yuan631111976/videostreamdecoder/blob/4bfc8ddf78a513af367da8060c27f6bed5d59696/AVDecoder.cpp . Hope these helps.